# Getting X & Y coordinates from graphics object

Tags: java, object, graphics, coordinates, keyevent

I have a problem. I'm creating this maze game using java for the very first time, 
and I have lots and lots of `graphics(g)` drawings/objects drawn through their own class.

What I want to get is the `X` and `Y` coordinate out of one of them.

`public static int` seems too hard to use in this case, without created an equal number of integers as there are drawings.

So, I need something to use instead of `getY()`:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        for (int i=0; i<=42; i++) {
            if(cx != rektangel[i].getY())  // I tried "getY()" with fail(kind of dumb since it's used for mouselistener?

            cirkel[0].move(-10, 0);
            this.cx += -10;
            repaint();


    }
}
```

Information you might need to know in this code:

- `rektangel(the name)` = rectangle in english.
- `cirkel` is one object/drawing ==> I simply used a `static int` `cx` & `cy` for this guy to see it's coordinates.
- Where it says `i<42;` ==> shows that it's ALOT of drawn objects. (`static int` won't be optimal)

=============ANSWERED======ANSWERED=======ANSWERED=======ANSWERED==========
Sorry, but for some reason I can't comment your answers. The result is ridiculously laughable. I'm currently staying up late to finish my code for a homework I have. Thanks for your solution, and MadProgrammers comment. Here's my rectangle-class:

```
public class Rektangel {
   private int width,height;
   private int x,y; <---this row private
   Color c;
   public static int karta = 1;
   public static int rx = 0;
   public static int ry = 0;
}
```

The easiest thing in the world.. I had tried using `rectangle[i].x` in the previous code, but didn't work. Know why? Because I wrote private instead of public x & y. Sorry for the inconvenience and once again, Thanks!

Comment: `Graphics` is a virtual concept, it has no concept of position or size.  The objects themselves, that you are rendering to the `Graphics` context, should be maintaining their own concept of position and size

Comment: Although you apparently can't comment on MadProgrammer's answer, you should still be able to comment on the question itself.

Comment: Now I can, but I couldn't yesterday. Something went wrong :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should maintain the position and size of each object within itself and provide a `getX`, `getY` and `getWidth` and `getHeight` method for each, this way, they become self managing, knowing where they are and how big they should be...